# Prove that there are no positive real numbers $x$, $y$, $z$ such that $ (12x^2 + yz)(12y^2 + xz)(12z^2 + xy) = 2021x^2y^2z^2.$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, contest-math, recreational-mathematics, education, math-history

Prove that there are no positive real numbers $x, y, z$ such that : $(12x^2 + yz)(12y^2 + xz)(12z^2 + xy) = 2021x^2y^2z^2$.
I managed to simplify it to $12(x^3z^3 + y^3z^3+x^3y^3) + xyz (x^3+y^3+z^3) = (73/3)(x^2y^2z^2$) but i still can't figure it out.
Can someone help?

Comment: You did you get the 2nd equality?  The 1st equation has only degree-6 terms when expanded.  How come you get degree-two terms on the LHS in the 2nd equation?

Comment: OIC.  There's a typo in $x+y+z$.  It shld b $x^3+y^3+z^3$.

Comment: yeap, i corrected it, thanks

Comment: The equation is homogeneous of degree $6$ in $x,y,z$. It just suffices to look for solutions to $(12x^3+1)(12y^3+1))(12z^3+1) = 2021$ subject to $xyz = 1$.
Now $\log(12e^t+1)$ is a convex function in $t$, by Jensen....

Comment: applied on points $3\log x$, $3 \log y$ and $3 \log z$, whose average is zero, so that the RHS of applied Jensen ineq becomes log 13.  Some tidying up would lead to 13³ = 2197 > 2021.

Comment: Do not vandalize your own question.

Answer (score 2):

Following what you have left off, apply the AM-GM inequality to both factors : $x^3z^3+z^3y^3+x^3y^3 \ge 3x^2y^2z^2, x^3+y^3+z^3 \ge 3xyz$ and simplify the LHS  you see that LHS > RHS . Done

Comment: i'm sorry but i don't understand how you got x3z3+z3y3+x3y3≥3x2y2z2

Comment: @Anonymous: $x^3z^3+z^3y^3+x^3y^3 \ge 3\sqrt[3]{x^3z^3\cdot z^3y^3\cdot x^3y^3} = 3\sqrt[3]{x^6y^6z^6} = 3x^2y^2z^2$.

Comment: thank you so much! i got it now